# Silent installation of .NET framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, windows-services

I need to perform a silent installation of .NET Framework 4.5, along with an ASP.NET Core api that runs as a service, because for this api to work, you need this version of the framework installed. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: What Windows version? .net 4.5 comes pre installed since win 8.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

Answer (score 2):

You must provide the .net 4.5 framework installation as an .msi package if you want the server/user to install the framework on their computer. Otherwise they need to install it beforehand for your .net core api to work.

Unfortunately .net 4.5 does not allow you to do a "Self Contained" deployment package like .Net Core does.

If you are able to convert the functionality to pure .net core, then you could absolutely deploy a self contained package to run the APi and the user never needs to know how to install the proper framework for your application to work, obviously this mos likely won't be possible in some situations.

EDIT: You can either manually execute or create a quick console app to execute a powershell script to install the .net 4.5 framework.

This may work or get you on the right path. Instead of using a local path maybe you can pass in an http link or a shared drive elsewhere on your network. I only use powershell scripts sometimes so this may need a bit more research to meet your company architecture.

```
PS C:\Users\VPS1146858Admin\Downloads> Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\VPS1146858Admin\Downloads\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/q /norestart" -Wait
```

Comment: This is my problem, the way this api should work, it has to be a core application with a .net 4.5 template, to be able to run as a service, this way it is self-hosting, however it needs .net, like Installation will be done by commands, can not have human interaction, until some window can appear, but that does not ask to click

Comment: To run the service and execute this command "sc create Api.Servico binPath= C:\GestorServico\Api.Servico.exe start= auto" 

after this "sc start Api.Servico" 

I found this example in the documentation: "dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe /norestart /passive /showrmui /ChainingPackage Contoso"

But it does not suit my need

Comment: If you need to complete this without user interaction, you best bet would be to execute a powershell script froma seperate C# program or manually. Then in your powershell script you pass in all of the comands that would be asked.  I edited my answer to include that command

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll test